# Responsive resize jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a problem with responsive resize in jQuery. I have dynamic divs that I want to move to another div. When the screen size is changing I have the same width, height and position to my divs. How can i fix it? I want, when the screen size is changing then the divs size also with the same position. I was thinking about $(window).resize(function(){});, but how can i do it, can someone help me with that?

```js
$('.box').each(function() { $('.box').draggable({containment: '#boxid'});});
$('.box').each(function() { $('.box').resizable();});
```

```css
#boxid {
    height: 750px;
    border: 5px dotted #292929;        
}

.box {
    background:rgb(107, 193, 243);
    cursor:move;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
<div class="row">
    <div id="boxid" class="col-xs-12">
    <!-- hier die Position änder -->
    </div>
</div>
<!--here I start the foreach -->
    <div id="id" class="box" style="top:50px; left:50px; width:50px; height:50px;">           
        <p id="top"></p>
        <p id="left"></p>  
        <p id="height"></p>
        <p id="width"></p>          
    </div>
        <div id="id" class="box" style="top:50px; left:50px; width:50px; height:50px;">           
        <p id="top"></p>
        <p id="left"></p>  
        <p id="height"></p>
        <p id="width"></p>          
    </div>
<!--here I end the foreach -->
```

**Here is the problem:**

[image]

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @SmitRaval https://jsfiddle.net/cristiannn/ztf7pry6/38/ here you have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution by using `$(window).resize()`.

Within the callback check if the width/height has changed and adjust the `.box`-elements `left`/`width` and `top`/`height` properties according to the changes.

The callback body of `$(window).resize()` is wrapped in a `setTimeout(...)` to avoid executing the code every time the event is fired - leads to imprecise changes.

```js
$('.box').each(function() { $('.box').draggable({containment: '#boxid'});});
$('.box').each(function() { $('.box').resizable();});

let boxH = $("#boxid").height(),
    boxW = $("#boxid").width(),
    doit;

$(window).on('resize', function() {

  clearTimeout(doit);
  
  doit = setTimeout(function() {
  
    let box  = $("#boxid"),
        newH = box.height(),
        newW = box.width();

    if (newH != boxH) {

      $('.box').each(function() {

        let prop = newH / boxH,
            self = $(this),
            sT   = Number(self.css('top').slice(0,-2)),
            sH   = Number(self.css('height').slice(0,-2));

        self.css({'top': sT * prop});
        self.css({'height': sH * prop});
        
        console.log("TOP/LEFT", self.css('top'), self.css('left'));

      });

    }

    if (newW != boxW) { 

      $('.box').each(function() {

        let prop = newW / boxW,
            self = $(this),
            sL   = Number(self.css('left').slice(0,-2)),
            sW   = Number(self.css('width').slice(0,-2));

        self.css({'left': sL * prop});
        self.css({'width': sW * prop});

        console.log("TOP/LEFT", self.css('top'), self.css('left'));
        
      });

    }

    boxH = newH;
    boxW = newW;
    
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
#boxid {
    height: 750px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px dotted #292929;        
}

.box {
    background:rgb(107, 193, 243);
    cursor:move;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
<div class="row">
    <div id="boxid" class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="id1" class="box" style="top:50px; left:50px; width:50px; height:50px;">           
          <p id="top"></p>
          <p id="left"></p>  
          <p id="height"></p>
          <p id="width"></p>          
      </div>
      <div id="id2" class="box" style="top:50px; left:50px; width:50px; height:50px;">           
          <p id="top"></p>
          <p id="left"></p>  
          <p id="height"></p>
          <p id="width"></p>          
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for your help that is what i need but i still have a problem there because the box must to be out side of div row like in my example that's why i am getting this problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcgUl.jpg

Comment: then simply move the `.box`-elements out of the `#boxid`

Comment: yes i have done this but i am getting this problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcgUl.jpg

Comment: Sorry but I dont really understand you problem - you want the `.box`-elements to be outside of the `#boxid` or not? What shall the picture tell me?

Comment: i have an div row an there i should to move my box that are outside of div. And when i olen the console i get this problem  i.stack.imgur.com/zcgUl.jpg   and i think that the problem is because in your code the box are inside of row.

Comment: no I got what you meant - this can be simply fixed by not using the `$(window).width()/height()` but instead that of  `$("#boxid")`. I edited the above code. Also changed the width of the `#boxid` so it gets clear

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ui.intersect = function () { return true; };

$('.box').each(function() {


$('.box').resizable();
});

$('.box').each(function() {

$(".box").draggable({ 
    revert: 'valid',  
    containment: '#lager',
        drag: function() {
                var top = $(this).offset().top;
                var left = $(this).offset().left;
                $("#top").html(top);
                $("#left").html(left);
                },
                  stop: function(e, ui) {
    var perc = ui.position.left / ui.helper.parent().width() * 100;
    ui.helper.css('left', perc + '%');
    }     
    }); 
});

$('.box').droppable({  tolerance: 'touch'});
});
```

Convert position to percentage on **STOP** event. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztf7pry6/42/)

Comment: but what about the position and the size?

Comment: I didn't get you? @CristianCănănău

Comment: when the box divs are near to another and the screen size is changing then one div overlap another div. And when you have a big div it will be out of div **containment** .